# Put UIView above UITableView with section

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I want to put a UIView above a UITableView with Sections.

[image]

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.register(ActivityCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
    //tableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 0, 0)
    objectArray = [Objects(sectionName: "sec 1", sectionObjects: ["sdqdsq", "sdsqdqsd", "dsqdsqd", "dsqqsdds"]),Objects(sectionName: "sec 2", sectionObjects: ["sdqdsq", "sdsqdqsd", "dsqdsqd", "dsqqsdds"]),Objects(sectionName: "sec 3", sectionObjects: ["sdqdsq", "sdsqdqsd", "dsqdsqd", "dsqqsdds"])]
    setupProfilBar()
}

let profilBar: profilMenu = {
    let pb = profilMenu()
    pb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return pb
}()

func setupProfilBar() {
    view.addSubview(profilBar)
    profilBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    profilBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 64).isActive = true
    profilBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

How can i fix this ? thanks

Comment: Add subview a custom UIView to your ViewController's view where you have added the UITableView, and call the bringSubviewToFront from the ViewController.

Comment: Do you want your UIView above the UITableView?

Comment: You want this for just first section or for all section?

Comment: @Ishika Yes i want

Comment: Then you must try Sreekanth's answer he just gave.

Comment: @Sreekanth I don't understand what you say :/

Comment: First off, you need to use a UIViewController instead of a UITableviewController. Using Mainstoryboard, place your profile view i.e profile bar above the tableview and that should be it. Setup the table view as you like with the delegate methods for sections

Comment: @AntoineGalpin. If you have added your tableview inside a UIViewController, say MyViewController, in the place where you need to add the view, for example in the viewDidLoad, create a UIView object programatically like, UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourTableview.bounce];[ self.view addSubView: customView]. This will add the view on top of UITableView.Then you can bring the newly created view to top of the hierarchy by calling [self.view bringSubViewToFront:customView].

Comment: Do you want the section to work exactly like normal section work, i.e section header gets scrolled if another section header collides with it?

Comment: @Sreekanth can i do this with directly with UITableViewController or i need to user UIViewController?

Comment: @DrPatience can i do this with directly with UITableViewController or i need to user UIViewController?

Comment: @AntoineGalpin I prefer to use UIViewController. So you have more flexibility in customizing.

Comment: If you use UIViewController, then you can even directly add the view from the storyboard itself. Adding some movement animation will also be more easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an even easier method than mentioned in the comments:

You can set the `tableHeaderView`-property of your `UITableView`. This is a header above the whole table. (not a section header!).

Add this code in your `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let v = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 200))
v.backgroundColor = UIColor.red  
tableView.tableHeaderView = v
```

This would be the result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set your custom view as the table view's tableHeaderView property. There's no need to use a UIViewController instead of a UITableViewController as others have mentioned. [Here's the relevant Apple Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614904-tableheaderview)